# Linking to a static page

Tags: php, yii

I am a complete Yii newbie so please forgive a simple question. I've been reading up on various posts and can't find anything that works. All I'm trying to do is setup a Yii site (which I've done) and then link to a static page using my Main layout.

Below are the three files I think are relevant:

- **index.php:** the view I show on my homepage as content with the main layout
- **terms_of_use.php:** the view I'm unsuccessfully trying to get to appear in the main layout
- **main.php:** my master layout

Within the footer of the main layout, the link to the static page is:

```
<a href="index.php?r=site/page&view=terms_of_use">Terms of Use</a>
```

When I click on it, it generates what I think is the correct url in the brower address bar:

```
http://localhost/Company/index.php?r=site/page&view=terms_of_use
```

but what gets shown is the content of index.php, not terms_of_use.php. I'm using the default SiteController. Is there something special about index.php I don't know about, or am I doing something else dumb? Thanks for any help.

**views/site/index.php:**

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<div id="content" class = "clearfix">
    <div class="threeColBlock">
        <div class="padded">
            <h2 class="pageTitle">Heading 1</h2>
                <p>Blurb 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="threeColBlock">
        <div class="padded">
            <h2 class="pageTitle">Heading 2</h2>
            <p>Blurb 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="threeColBlock">
        <div class="padded">
            <h2 class="pageTitle">Heading 3</h2>
            <p>Blurb 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**views/site/pages/terms_of_use.php:**

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - About';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'About',
);
?>

<div id="content" class = "clearfix">
    <h2 class="pageTitle">Terms of Use</h2>
    <div class = "smallText">
        <p>
            Some legal junk
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**views/layouts/views/main.php:**

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="language" content="en" />

    <!-- blueprint CSS framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/form.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/marketing.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/cssmenu.css" media="screen" />

    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header"  class="clearfix">
        <div id="logo"><image src="images/logo,56x38,trans(white).gif"></div>
        <div id="logoName">Company</div>
        <div id="topRight">Bla bla bla</b></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='dummy.com'><span>home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>products</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='dummy.com'><span>prod1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='dummy.com'><span>prod2</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='dummy.com'><span>prod3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='dummy.com'><span>about</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='dummy.com'><span>contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainImageContainer">
        <div id="mainImage">
            <image src = "images/main_image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

</div><!-- page -->

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright &copy 2011 Company. All rights reserved. | <a href="index.php?r=site/page&view=terms_of_use">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>

</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. I had enabled the urlManager in config/main.php. If I change my original link to the following then I get what I want.

```
http://localhost/Company/index.php/site/page/view/terms_of_use
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your specific question, I believe you may have forgotten the step of overriding the `actions()` method in the default site controller - though that raises the question: Which version of the Yii framework are you using? The override is already included in Yii 1.1.12.

Also, as per the comments on that yii wiki article:

> If you happen to use accessRules, don't forget to add 'page' (or
>   whatever name you have in) to allowed action as well.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/ is a great post on using static pages in Yii, the bulk of it:

> First, in the default SiteController (or other controller if you
>   like), override the actions() method as follows,

```
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}
```

> Second, create a folder protected/views/site/pages.
>
> Third, save each static page as a PHP file under this folder. For
>   example, we can save the "about this site" page as about.php. Note,
>   these pages will use the application's default layout. Therefore, only
>   the main content needs to be saved in each file.
>
> We are done! To access a static page, e.g., the about page, we can use
>   the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?r=site/page&view=about
```

Comment: Yes, I've read that article. The current version of yii ships with the action() override already place in the controller. The directory structure and location for static pages is also out-of-the-box, and is what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to hardcode urls, instead use functions like [`createUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail), (there are other variants of it).

When you hardcode urls the problem you faced could arise, `createUrl` takes into account your urlManager configuration, and generates a url accordingly, so when you make changes you don't have to go to every view and change the url again.

You can use it like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/site/page',array('view'=>'terms_of_use')); ?>">About</a>
```

Or use [`CHtml::link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#link-detail):

```
echo CHtml::link('About',array('/site/page', 'view'=>'temrs_of_use'));
```